# Find the number of solutions of the equation using generating functions

Tags: generating-functions

$$u_1+u_2+...+u_7 = 23$$ Where $$ 1\le u_i \le 7 =1,...,7 $$
So far, I've gotten up to the point where you actually find the generating function. so from my understanding so far there are 7 integers which must sum to 23 and lie between 2 and 6, I need to find the coefficient of  23  in:

$$(x^1 +...+x^7)^7$$
Then I get stuck here: 
$$x^7(1+...+x^6)^7$$
After this point i'm not sure how to get the generating function and solve the question! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use the formula for the sum of a geometric series, then use the binomial theorem expansion of $(1-x)^{-7}$.

Comment: working through i've gotten 12C6 -7 * 12C6

Comment: The [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E7%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6%29%5E7) is $40166$ if you want to verify it